# OpenGL glBlendFuncSeparate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, opengl

I need some help with OpenGL textures masking. I have it working but need to find some other blending function parameters to work in other way. 
Now I have:

```
//Background 
...code...
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
...code

//Mask
...code...
    glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE, GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO);
...code...

//Foreground
...code
    glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
...code
```

Now it sets foreground's opacity to 0 (fills with background texture) where mask is transparent. I need it to react to mask's colors. I mean something like setting foregrounds opacity depending on mask's color. For example if mask is black (0.0,0.0,0.0) then the opacity of that place in foreground is 0 (is filled with background), and if mask is white (1.0,1.0,1.0) then the opacity of foreground is 1 (not filled with background). It can be in reverse consequence (white = opacity 0, black = opacity 1). I just need it to work depending on color.

My current result's visualization bellow.

---

Background:
[image]

Mask (circle is transparent):
[image]

Foreground:
[image]

Result:
[image]

---

And I want it to work like this:

Background:
[image]

Mask (circle is white, background is black):
[image]

Foreground:
[image]

Result:
[image]

---

So that later it could be used like this:

Background:
[image]

Mask (circle is white, background is black):
[image]

Foreground:
[image]

Result:
[image]

---

Attempt with @Gigi solution:
[image]

Comment: Could you add an "expected" result image as well?

Comment: Have you considered using a pixel shader?

Comment: yes like @ananthonline said if pixel shaders are an option than this solution would be rather simple

Comment: Actually I have no idea how to set up pixel shaders and use them, thats why I'm using blending. It looks much easier

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is what you want:

---

1) Clear the destination image:

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

---

2) Draw the background, masking out the alpha channel:

```
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_FALSE);
```

---

3) Draw the "masking overlay", masking out the color channels:

```
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE);
```

---

4) Draw the foreground, enabling blending:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendEquationSeparate(GL_FUNC_ADD, GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
```

---

Note: The overlay image must have the alpha channel specified.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now wherever I draw my mask, the whole foreground gets full transparent (alpha = 0). And I need it to get transparent only where in mask is for example black color.

Comment: @JuliusPetraška: Your mask image need to have the alpha channel filled with alpha=0 inside the circle and alpha=1 outside the circle... just like the mask image you posted, but with an actual "alpha channel".

Comment: I know. And I used image as you described (circle alpha =0, outside alpha = 1. My mask is just small image, and the background and foreground is big, so when I paint my mask it has to mask only small part of image. As it does in earlier variant of my code. And now it just masks out all image.

Comment: @JuliusPetraška: How are you "painting" the mask?

Comment: @JuliusPetraška: Strange indeed. I suspect you have some other kind of problem elsewhere.

Comment: Well, if there would be more problems, then my current using way would't be working I guess. I think I just need to find good blend combination for it. But anyway, thank you very much for help :)